# How parse and convert xml date and time into seconds

Tags: c, xml

how can i parse this value P5Y2M10DT15H

where y = years M = months D = Days and T = time H = hours,

whenever i get 5 i have to multiply that num by 3162240 (num of seconds in a year) +  2*num of seconds in a month + 10 * num of seconds in a day + 15 * num of seconds in a hour

Comment: How many seconds are there in February of a leap year? -- or, to put it another way -- you better rethink your strategy for whatever you want to do.

Comment: @pmg : i thought of checking those things during the time of coding... now  i have not included that in the question

Answer (score 0):

[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) may work ...

```
int y, m, d, h;
int seconds;
char val[] = "P5Y2M10DT15H";
if(sscanf(val, "P%dY%dM%dDT%dH", &y, &m, &d, &h) != 4) /* error */;
seconds = y*3162240 + m*<WHATEVER> + d*24*3600 + h*3600;
```